# return value: none -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that takes three lists of integers, l1, l2, and l3, and returns
a list of all tuples, where each tuple (a,b,c) is such that a is from l1, b is
from l2 and c is from l3 and a+b=c.

Expected Output:

```
[(2,5,7), (3,4,7), (3,5,8)]
```

The output I got:

```
None
```

Here is the code that I have written:

```
def threeList(l1, l2, l3):
   result = []
   for num in list3:
      for x in list1:
        for y in list2:
          if x + y == num:
            tuples = (x,y,num)
            list_of_tuples = result.extend(tuples)
            return list_of_tuples
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5]
list3 = [7,8]
threeList(list1, list2, list3)
```

Comment: `extend` returns `None`, which is what you're returning. You probably also don't want to `return` inside the loop, but after all the loops.

Comment: `extend` is an in-place method which returns `None`.

Comment: How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`extend` is an in-place method which returns `None`.

Change your code to:

```
def threeList(l1, l2, l3):
    result = []
    for num in l3:
        for x in l1:
            for y in l2:
                if x + y == num:
                    tuples = (x, y, num)
                    result.append(tuples)
    return result


list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5]
list3 = [7, 8]
print(threeList(list1, list2, list3))
```

Output:

`[(2, 5, 7), (3, 4, 7), (3, 5, 8)]`

Explanation :

I used `append` instead of `extend` because we want the tuple `tuples` itself not the items inside it. Also I replaced the names `list3`, `list1`, `list2` with `l3`, `l1`, `l2` respectively because these are the actual values passed to the function, if your code works now is because `list1`, `list2`, `list3` are exist in outside and those are referenced inside the function. Then after the loop finishes I return the `result` which is a list of tuples.

This was to fix your solution, but a better alternative solution is to use itertools modules like `product` in your situation.

Comment: @NisaAslan Happy to help, In stackoverflow you can accept one answer which you find most helpful by click on the "check" icon which is located below the upvoting and downvoting section in answers post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools as it

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5]
list3 = [7,8]

[(x,y,x+y) for x,y in it.product(list1,list2) if x+y in list3]
```

which returns:

```
> [(2, 5, 7), (3, 4, 7), (3, 5, 8)]
```

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is a clean replacement for nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Extend modifies the object itself. It does not return anything.

```
result.extend(tuples)
return result
```

Also note your code snippet is not working. So it is hard to spot your exact issue.

- Did you make a typo?
- Indentation wrong?
- etc

Comment: @NisaAslan: There are at least two things wrong with your code.